# LWC datatable Header wrapping

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lwc-oss

I am working on a LWC component where in a lightning datatable I have more than 7-8 columns. When I add the component into detail section of a record page, the headers of the table is getting truncated. While I used wrapText: true, seems it only works on the data but not on the headers. Is there any way I can wrap the column names ? Thanks in advance.
HTML:

```
 <lightning-datatable
key-field="Id"
data={allConsdata}
columns={columnsCon}
hide-checkbox-column="true">
```

JS:

```
@track columnsCon = [
    {
    label: 'Contact/rep',
    fieldName: 'nameUrl',
    type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, 
    target: '_self'},
    sortable: true,
    wrapText: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Title',
        fieldName: 'Title',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true,
        wrapText: true
    },....
```

[image: This is the screenshot of my LWC where the column names higlighted in yeloow are getting truncated]

Want something like this:
[image]

Comment: hello @arita, Did you find a solution on this issue? I would be interested if you have one

Comment: @JulienSouchi please check my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 8):

### Update

Spring 2024 and later releases support Header Wrapping Natively. Set the `wrap-table-header` property of datatable as `true` to wrap the headers. This will work if your org is in Spring 2024 or later release versions.

---

I had come across the same problem I solved it by using custom styles loaded from the static resource. Put the below code in the static resource and load that using `loadStyle` in the Lightning web component.

```
.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-th__action .slds-truncate{
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: unset;
    white-space: pre-line;
    /* word-wrap: break-word; */
}

.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-th__action {
    height: 5rem;
}

.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-line-height_reset{
    height: 3rem;
}
```

And then add class `wrapped-header-datatable` to your `lightning-datatable`.

**Please note that you might need to tweak the heights a little bit.**

I have written a detailed blog about this -> [LWC datatable header wrapping hack](https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/03/datatable-header-wrapping-lwc.html)

Comment: Good blog. Unfortunately not working for me. Is that hack still working?

Comment: @SergioAndresPedrazaJerez yes it is still working.

Comment: Thank you @rahul-gawale. If the static resource is private, the solution does not work. I set it to public and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

why not use  min-column-width attribute where you can set the minimum column width for the table and you will get the scroller along x-axis which you can use to scroll through rest of the columns

```
  <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                min-column-width="100"
                >
        </lightning-datatable>
```

it will look something like this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/6PhM9grWA/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @User6670. I have already tried this before and you mentioned, it gives a horizontal scrollbar which I don't want but wrapped column names.