# LWC datatable wrap text column header

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

How can I make the column header in the LWC datatable to be wrapped as well ?
wrapText:true only applies for the rows
[image]

```
<lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            data={contracts}
            columns={contractsColumns}
            max-row-selection="1"
            onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
        >
       </lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: There is a previous thread about this from 2020, have you tried [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301514/lwc-datatable-header-wrapping)?

Comment: I'm looking for a simpler solution. I also tried it but didn't work